# Wrapping AJAX in a function seems to make it lose async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script I'm using to schedule resources using an API and a list in CSV format. The script currently loops through the CSV and fires off a call to a function that has the API calls in it. The AJAX calls are nested (Create a Reservation->Take the reservation number and add a resource->Validate the reservation->Submit the reservation). The problem is that after the original AJAX call, it seems to hang until all of the AJAX calls have completed. There doesn't seem to be any asynchronicity going on.

```
for(line in CSV)
{
   makeAPICalls(line)
}

function makeAPICalls(line)
{
$.ajax("Create Reservation").then(function(){ 
    $.ajax("Add Resource to Reservation").then(function(){
        $.ajax("Validate Reservation").then(function(){
           $.ajax("Confirm Reservation")
           })
        })
    })
}
```

The first API call ("Create Reservation") completes, and then waits for all of the other lines in the CSV to make that call, then they ALL move on to the next step ("Add Resource to Reservation"). I was wondering if the system was just moving too quickly, so there wasn't a chance for everything to get "out of sync", so I added a delay before makeAPICalls(), but it still waited. Once the CSV loop finished, all the AJAX calls moves from ("Create Reservation") to the then("Add Resource to Reservation").

Is this as expected? Ideally I'd like each call to makeAPICalls() to finish as quickly as possible, with no regards for any other calls (which I kind of thought was what async was all about, but it doesn't seem to be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) the requests. If your requests are not dependent on each other, you can call them without using `.then()`.

Comment: Sorry, it may not have been clear. Each request in the chain depends on the step before it, but each call to the function does not depend on other calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is quite correct.  I don't know how you are putting in the delay but it probably won't help since JavaScript is single-threaded.

If you want all the steps to complete for a specific csv line you could have your function process the list one-by-one.  You could even have the last step call back into the function with the next index to process.